# Is there an alternative to ng-init to execute all the times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

First of all. I'm sorry if my explanation is confused. If you see the code below which is my index.html from my Ionic project. It executes ok in the first time, but as soon as I add a new word and in the ng-repeat it has more than 1 word.. the function inside the ng-init execute just one time, just for the last word (string) added. Not for all again.

So, the ng-init is executing just one time... not for all the words. Is there any alternative for ng-init?

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button ng-click="vm.showAddBirthdayModal()" class="button button-icon icon ion-android-add">
    </button>
</div>

<ion-item ng-repeat="b in vm.birthdays" ng-click="vm.showEditBirthdayModal(b)">
    <div style="float: left">
        <ion-text>{{b.Name}} : </ion-text>
        <ion-text ng-init="getTwitter(this.b.Name)">{{twitts[b.Name].count}}</ion-text>                 
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

This is my getTwitter:

```
$scope.getTwitter = function(hashtag) {  



   $scope.twitts = {};

   var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

   $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)   
   .then(function (position) {

      var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
      $scope.lat = lat;

      var long = position.coords.longitude;
      $scope.long = long;

        $ionicLoading.show();

        $http.get('https://twitter.net/api/twitter/count?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + long + '&keywords=' + hashtag + '')
        .success(function(twitts) {
            $scope.twitts[hashtag] = twitts;
            //console.log('Twitts: '+$scope.twitts);
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        })
        .error(function(erro) {
            //$scope.twitts = twitts;
            console.log(erro);
        })
        .finally(function() {
        // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        });

        console.log('Latitude: '+ lat + ' Longitude: ' + long)

   }, function(err) {

      console.log(err)

   });
```

}

Comment: You almost never need `ng-init`.  Why not just set it to the value of a variable set on your controller?

Comment: Yes... drop the init and post code for controller or `getTwitter`?

Comment: What should I use so instead?

Comment: `ng-init` shouldn't be used in production code at all, it always indicates lousy app design. Make `getTwitter` to return an object, the method will be called on each digest when it is bound `{{getTwitter(b.Name).count}}`. You can cache http request and returned object depending on your needs, so the API won't be spammed on every digest.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change getTwitter and make it return an object. I changed also the index.html to: <ion-text>{{getTwitter('chuva').count}}</ion-text>, and now it's executing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't apply this code in your controller but in a service. You could do something like:

Service

```
.service('tweetSrv', function ($q, $http, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading) {

    var getTweets = function (twitts) {
        var posOptions = {
            timeout: 10000,
            enableHighAccuracy: false
        };


        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {

                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                //                $scope.lat = lat;

                var long = position.coords.longitude;
                //                $scope.long = long;

                $ionicLoading.show();

                $http.get('https://twitter.net/api/twitter/count?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + long + '&keywords=' + hashtag + '')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        resolve(response);
                        //console.log('Twitts: '+$scope.twitts);
                        $ionicLoading.hide();

                    }, function () {
                        reject("Something's wrong");
                    })

                console.log('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Longitude: ' + long);

            }, function (err) {

                console.log(err)

            })

        })
    }

    return {
        getTweets: getTweets
    }
})
```

And in your controller

```
var birthdaysLength = $scope.birthdays.length();
var i = 0;

var getBirthdaysTweets = function (name, index) {
    tweetSrv.getTweets(name).then(function (tweetsCount) {
        $scope.birthdays[index].tweets = tweetsCount;
        index++;
        if (index < birthdaysLength)
            getBirthdaysTweets($scope.birthdays[index].name, index);
        else {
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            console.log("Done. I've loaded tweets for all birthdays");
        }
    }, function (errorString) {
        console.log(errorString);
    })
}

getBirthdaysTweets($scope.birthdays[i].name, i);
```

Comment: if there is a way to reload the page after I click in the save button in the modal. It would resolve my problem. Do you know if there is a way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need something like that ? What exactly you need to do ?

Comment: My index.html just works when it loads for the first time... this is a prototype so I'm not interested in performance or something like that. Just load index.html again would resolve my life. :)